# OSX / Unix Terminal Color Template Change

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-lion

I've been trying to decorate my Terminal on my MacOSX 10.7.3. As i surfed and found is to write following color codes into the file called `.bash_profile`:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

The problem is **WHERE TO SAVE THIS FILE?**

Answer (score 0):

In first place you should use the terminal preferences under the menu `Terminal > Preferences > Settings` to change this kind of things. (Or maybe not)

If you still want to go text mode, since OS X is UNIX based, you should be able to create the file `.bash_profile` inside your home directory and it will be loaded.

You need to: `touch ~/.bash_profile`

Then open the file vi `~/.bash_profile`, press `i` to enter in text insert mode, paste your text and press `esc` them type `:wq`, press `enter` and the file should be saved.

Your options should be like this

```
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
export CLICOLOR='Yes'
export LSCOLORS=''
export LSCOLORS='Bxgxfxfxcxdxdxhbadbxbx'
```

Comment: Don't link them, since the `.bashrc` file gets read after `.bash_profile` on any login terminal. That would cause it to be read twice. If you want something to work everywhere, put it in the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun at least in OSX if I place the options only under `.bashrc` they won't take effect. Maybe they are overwritten by the setting on the OSX Terminal GUI. Placing them only at `.bash_profile` works fine for local logins.

Comment: There's no need to `touch` the file before you edit it or before you `echo >>` (append, or even `echo >` - overwrite).

Comment: @TCB13 according to the bash [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), there are various options that can have this effect. The biggest one is that if a shell is a login shell, it does not read `.bashrc` by default. This is why most people have `.bash_profile` source `.bashrc`. See [here](https://github.com/srathbun/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile) for an example.

Comment: Terminal options will not allow customisation of `ls` output colours – you can define the colour scheme there, but is mapping to coloured directory listings is up to `LSCOLOR`. Also note that `--color=auto` has no effect on OS X whatsoever, as OS X uses BSD’s external `ls` command. The correct option for coloured output with that is `-G`, but that isn’t needed either, as it is equivalent to setting `CLICOLOR` (see the `ls` man page).

Comment: @shlck: you are right OS X Terminal.app starts all base windows / tab shells as login shells (but not sub shells launched from there – these are standard non-login shells), which means that `.bash_profile` is always processed. `.bashrc` however is not, unless you source it in `.bash_profile` – bash only processes `.bashrc` on interactive *non-login* shells (see Invocation section of bash man page).

Comment: Oh, and no need to use `vi` to edit `.bashrc` – this is OS X, `open -e .bashrc` will get you TextEdit.

Comment: You got the username ping wrong, but yes, you're correct, my mistake! @kopischke

Comment: GUYS please i'm getting so confused. I'm sorry but is there a simple solution or not here?

Comment: @4lvin read my answer and try it. Simple and effective.